# Visual Studio 2008: Synchronizing project structure with underlying file structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way of making the (ASP.NET MVC) project structure reflect the underlying physical directory in the same way as ASP.NET Website projects are treated? - so you don't have to explicitly add files that are already in place via the Solution Explorer too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using Chris Pietschmann's instructions to [Convert an ASP.NET MVC application to a website project](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/08/How-To-Use-ASPNET-MVC-in-Website-rather-than-Web-Application-Project.aspx).

Though it looks like I'll lose some of the [suppport features for ASP.NET MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/12/19/asp-net-mvc-design-gallery-and-upcoming-view-improvements-with-the-asp-net-mvc-release-candidate.aspx) built into Visual Studio by doing this..